Azure DevOps Unit test issue
Having issues with cicd ado pipeline want to make unit test but can't generate report for the testing, ado identify files but somehow can't test them 
I have code coverage. Here is my template for the pipeline
  # Install dependencies
  - script: |
      echo "Installing dependencies..."
      python -m pip install mypy pytest pytest-azurepipelines pytest-cov pyspark
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  # Run MyPy type checks on each Python file individually
  - script: |
      echo "Running MyPy type checks on each file..."
      find $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name '*.py' | while read file; do
        mypy --strict "$file" || echo "MyPy found issues in $file"
      done
    displayName: 'Run MyPy Type Checks (Errors Non-Blocking)'

  # Run pytest with coverage and handle collection errors
  - script: |
      echo "Running tests with pytest..."
      # Debugging step: List Python files to verify paths
      echo "Listing Python files in $(Build.SourcesDirectory) to verify paths..."
      find $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name '*.py'

  # Publish test results
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test-output.xml'
      failTaskOnFailedTests: false

  # Publish code coverage results
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
      summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.xml'
      reportDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/htmlcov'
      failIfCoverageEmpty: false

  # Prepare SonarQube analysis
  - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
    inputs:
      SonarQube: ${{ parameters.sqConnection }}
      scannerMode: 'CLI'
      configMode: 'manual'
      cliProjectKey: "$(sq_project_key)"
      cliSources: '.'
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.xml
        sonar.junit.reportPaths=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test-output.xml

  # Run SonarQube analysis
  - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5

  # Publish SonarQube results
  - task: SonarQubePublish@5
    inputs:
      pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

I'm receiving the following error

How to execute unit test?

Have you run pytest in any of the script steps?

From the current pipeline definition that you shared, there was not pytest command in your script. But from the logs, we could see test session starts. May I know which step had incurred this issue? Have you tried running the pytest command like pytest --doctest-modules --junitxml=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/test-output.xml --cov=. --cov-report=xml:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.xml in your script to see how the tests are going? By the way, what is the command you can run to test locally? The required python version was 3.10?
